# Is it possible to stop tracking local changes to a file that you *do* want to be pulled down if changed in the repo?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-track

We have a config file in the repo which all the users contribute to based on their function.  For my local testing, I need to manually change two values in that config file, but I never want my changes committed back to the server.

I do however want to pull updates to the file if there's a newer version in the repo, even if that means my local changes will be overwritten.  That's fine, I can just make them again from a stash I created specifically to do exactly that.

What I'm wondering is if I can tell Git "Hey... I will *never* push back my local changes to the server, so don't show it to me as changed, but if *you* have new changes for me, lemme have them when I pull!"

Here's an example of what I'm after.

```
Server: VersionA
Local:  [Nothing]

(I do a Git Pull)

Server: VersionA
Local:  VersionA

(I make local changes)

Server: VersionA
Local:  VersionA (Modified)

(What I want...)

Server: VersionA
Local:  VersionA (Modified, but ignored locally by Git)

(Someone checks in an update to the file)    

Server: VersionB
Local:  VersionA (Modified, but local changes ignored by Git)

(I do a git Pull)

Server: VersionB
Local:  VersionB (This overwrites my local, modified VersionA)

(I then manually update VersionB with my stashed changes)

Server: VersionB
Local:  VersionB (modified, but local changes ignored by Git)
```

The `.gitignore` file doesn't apply here because that stops new files from being added, but again, this file has *already* been added.  I just want it to always ignore my local changes, as if they weren't there. I only care if the file has changed on the server.

So can Git be configured to do this?

Comment: I think you should change workflow and work with a copy of that file. In a repo, your team will store only an example of the file, and when it's changed you could merge your working and sample copies.

Answer (score 0):

> The `.gitignore` file doesn't apply here because that stops new files from being added, but again, this file has *already* been added.
>   I just want it to always ignore my local changes.

Another approach would be to make your modifications... in a *private* file, one which is not tracked and is ignored.

Meaning all the common contributions are done in a *template* file., used to *generate* the actual file (as a private non-versioned file, added to your `.gitignore`).

That generation would be automatic on `git checkout`.

First, rename your existing file:

```
git mv aConfigFile aConfigFile.tpl
git commit -m "record template config file"
```

Then add to `aConfigFile` to a `.gitignore` file: a `git status` won't show it anymore to be added/changed.

Now, declare a smudge **[content filter driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code)** which, automatically, will re-generate that file (ignored, since it is in `.gitignore`)

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/smudge.png]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

`smudge` script (which you can version): `YourScript`

```
copy aConfigFile.tpl aConfigFile
```

Declare the content filter driver in a versioned `.gitattributes`:

```
echo 'aConfigFile.tpl config' >> .gitattributes
```

That smudge 'config' content filter driver needs to be activated locally by each user cloning that repo.

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config filter.config.smudge YourScript
```

That last step is the only one each user need to do in order to benefit from the actual config file to be automatically generated on each `git checkout`.

Any modification done on the generated file will remain local.