# How to untrack specific file not removing from git repository

Tags: git

I'm a git user, but I have trouble related to file tracking.

There's a file in git repository, which is required to build project, but should be different locally in each local PC. I use jenkins to build project, which builds project based on git repository.

So, I need to ignore the file on my PC, but the file should be exist on git repository.

If I describe the file name in `.gitignore` file, the file is removed from git repository.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/51698863/6309

Answer (score 0):

One option is to version a `.template` version of this config file and a `setup` script.

Have Jenkins call the `setup` script, with options which will allow your project to be built on Jenkins.