# Exclude files from PR if only using statements change

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

My project uses Visual Studio 2017, Git, and Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS)

We're on a large project and, when doing refactoring, we can change the same using statement on LOTS of files. That makes it painful for reviewers to sort out when combing through my pull request. I'd love a way to either exclude files from a PR where only using statements have changed or maybe group those files together.

Does anyone know of a programmatic way of doing this? Or maybe an add-in for Azure Devops? I'll take any method of solving the problem or a "Write it and I'll use it" response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [check out your PR locally](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/), you can then make a diff between the PR branch and your main branch, conducting the review locally.

That gives you the opportunity to activate a smudge content filter driver ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51698863/6309)), which can (on checkout) automatically rewrite all you import with "import xxx", effectively rendering *all* imports identical (meaning, they won't show up in a diff).